# How to change Date/ Time of push in github repo?

Tags: git, github

I have my school project that I have to submit as an  final year project. I have commit hisike 4 months ago there?

Comment: It's possible I did the same thing with my friend's school project. 
  https://i.imgur.com/Jj7oyjG.png

Comment: @ademclk  what should I type in command line ? Can you please provide me entire command?

Comment: Note that each commit stores *two* date-and-time-stamps: author, and committer. Running `git push` transmits commits, which are immutable. Whether any recipient of a push (e.g., GitHub) add further timestamps outside Git is up to each recipient, but since commits are immutable, they cannot change the existing commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped my friend in school project with this.

Change the date whatever you want format: Year Month Day Hour Minute

```
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$(date -j -f '%Y%m%d%H%M' 201610160012) GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE" git commit -s -m "Your message"
```

Another version

```
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$(date -d'2022-03-18 18:30:18') GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE" git commit -s -m "message"
```

Comment: what is the entire command?

Comment: @SamRoger You're changing the author date and passing it as an argument for commit. This code works only in bash terminal. If you've windows then try using git bash to make it work.

Comment: It is working on git bash. I am able to change the commit message and shows the same on github repo but the date is not changing?

Comment: Github shows the committer date, AFAIK. You can fake that, too. But it has implications on the correct working of Git. I advise not to change it unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: @SamRoger I edited my answer with another version.